# Understanding how sys.dm_exec_requests represents queries being rolled back

Tags: sql-server, rollback, compression, kill

I'm not sure whether this was an actual problem or just a normal situation where I needed to wait for rollback to finish. In either case, some insight would be appreciated.

**Background details**

I manage a server running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 that has a fairly large table:

- 842 million rows at ~108 bytes each
- Clustered index (85 GB)
- 1 nonclustered index (8 GB)
- Page compression applied to both indexes

Admittedly, table design and change control in my current working environment are not good. Someone ran the following batch to convert 9 `decimal` columns to `numeric (18,6) NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col1] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col2] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col3] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col4] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col5] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col6] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col7] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col8] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[My_Table] ALTER COLUMN [Col9] NUMERIC(18,6) NULL
```

I think the purpose of the changes was purely for standardisation of data types across tables.

This ran for close to 24 hours and got partway through modifying `Col4`, at which point I killed it.

**What happened after I killed the query**

Four hours after killing the query, the row for the session in `sys.dm_exec_requests` showed a `status` of 'running', a `command` of 'KILLED/ROLLBACK' and a value of 0 for `percent_complete`.

I could tell the session was doing something because reads, writes, and CPU usage were still accumulating at a constant rate. The query was not blocked or waiting. There was little other activity on the server and I/O associated with this query was completing in <1ms according to Process Monitor.

**Why what `sys.dm_exec_requests` showed seemed odd to me**

This is confusing given that if I look at a killed query on another 2008 R2 server, `sys.dm_exec_requests` shows the session in a `status` of 'rollback', a `command` of 'AWAITING COMMAND', and a number reported for `percent_complete`.

The only difference I can find between these servers is that the former is 2008 R2 SP2 and the latter is 2008 R2 SP2 CU8.

**The actual question!**

What accounts for the difference in the way these rollbacks are reported in `sys.dm_exec_requests`?  For example, does a `status` of 'running' with a `command` of 'KILLED/ROLLBACK' indicate that the KILL command is still being processed, whereas a `status` of 'rollback' indicates that the query has progressed to performing the actual rollback?

The query finally rolled back, by the way. I never saw the status transition to `rollback` or a `percent_complete` reported even though I'm capturing `sp_whoisactive` output every 5 seconds.

Comment: I wrote about this [a long time ago](https://sqlblog.org/2008/07/01/sys-dm_exec_requests) and, at the time, I was seeing rollbacks display a `percent_complete` value - however, it likely depends on what operation is being rolled back, exactly. I've also filed a couple of Connect items (284207/354545/520072/641790), but Connect has been ungloriously retired.